# QTip2 ajax popup not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, qtip2

I am trying to display qtip popup via ajax with no success. I got the following code, but cant seem to detect whee am going wrong. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.tiplink').qtip({
        content:{
            var id = $(this).attr('rel');
            text: '<img class="" src="../images/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />',
            ajax:{
                url: 'pops.php',
                type: 'POST', 
                loading: false,
                data: 'id=' + id
            }
        },

        show: 'mouseover', // Show it on mouseover
        hide: {
            delay: 200,
            fixed: true // We'll let the user interact with it
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-shadow',
            width: 290 
        }
    });

});
</script>

<a href="#" class="tiplink" rel='1'>show me the popup1!</a>
<a href="#" class="tiplink" rel='2'>show me the popup2!</a>
<a href="#" class="tiplink" rel='3'>show me the popup3!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem; it seems to be related to the fact that **$('.myclass').qtip({})** can not reference more then one element.  In the event it does (and such as your example) you need to wrap the qtip() calls within an **each(function())** block...

With respect to your example, the following should fix your issue:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  // the each() call I was explaining above this code example
  $('.tiplink').each(function(){

    // Extract your variables here:
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('rel');

    // Now make your qtip() call
    $this.qtip({
      content:{
        text: '<img class="" src="../images/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />',
        ajax:{
          url: 'pops.php',
          type: 'POST', 
          loading: false,
          data: 'id=' + id
        }
      },
      show: 'mouseover', // Show it on mouseover
      hide: {
        delay: 200,
        fixed: true // We'll let the user interact with it
      },
      style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-shadow',
        width: 290 
      }
    });
  }); // end each(function()) call
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is some questions around that might help you
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950004/how-to-use-jquery-qtip-simple-example-please)

and the tutorial itself on qtip's site
[here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials/)

i don't see any other reason it shouldn't work if you do everything as written

Comment: On close examination, if i place the assignment of the id var before the qtip initialization like this:     
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.tiplink').qtip({
    content: { ...
 all works fine. What is missing or wrong here?

Comment: The problem wit the above is that the id var is always undefined. I need the id var to do ajax db queries..